# GWT freeze during RPC call

Tags: gwt

I'm doing some stuff using GWT with rpc calls in order to get MySQL queries. These queries can be big (up to 500 entries). When I do the RPC call, the browser freeze ( for example, my loading .gif image is frozen ). I thought using RPC call with asyncallback would avoid this problem but obviously It doesn't.

My tests are made on Eclipse (GWT dev plug in) in development mode so I was also wondering if the problem does not come from the server provided by Google. Moreover, I would like to know if this problem will stay when I will deploy the application to an other server. If no, could give me some advices to avoid this type of problems.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, are you running this query on the load of the application? If it is the case, then it is normal.

From my experience with **gwt, elcipse and Tomcat**, the freeze only happen in **Eclipse**. When you deploy your application on a server such as **Tomcat**, this problem will disappear even if the RPC call is on the load of the application.

Comment: In fact, it's undirectly called in the onModuleLoad() because I call loadVisualizationApi ( in onModuleLoad ) with a callback which make the rpc call so I think we can tell that the rpc call is made during the onModuleLoad function. Thank for your return of experience, I will try with tomcat.

Comment: Yes, everything called from the onModuleLoad is gonna freeze your application until it is finished. This is only in Eclipse